# Type of functions for Hyperledger Fabric Smart Contract

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, smartcontracts

I am using Hyperledger Fabric for my Energy Blockchain work. I am using Javascript for developing my Smart Contract. While writing functions for the smart contract, how much processing I am allowed to put there?

For example, if i put a simple optimization problem inside the smart contract will that work? My guess says, no, I should not, but can I have some logical explanation whether that should be done or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Hyperledger Fabric permits to write smart contracts in turing complete languages (Javascript, Go, Java).
The logics that you write in your smart contract must be deterministic because they are executed in different peers and they must return the same output in order to update the ledger.

If you need more information about smart contracts, here the official documentation:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/smartcontract/smartcontract.html#developing

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you can put full turing complete code in your smart contract code. But you also have to be careful in the amount of computational overhead you are asking your as well as peers of other organisations to perform. Ideally in a permissioned environment, if your code is too computationally expensive, your code might be rejected by smart contract auditing team (if there are any) before any actual production deployment.

But there are other mechanisms where you can employ special nodes to do off chain computations and keep stakes high, for others to point out errors if anyone puts malevolent computational results on chain.